# Replacing environment variables in a properties file

Tags: linux

In Linux, say I have the following file (e.g. conf.properties):

```
HOST_URL=http://$HOSTNAME
STD_CONFIG=http://$HOSTNAME/config
USER_CONFIG=http://$HOSTNAME/config/$unconfigured
```

I want to create another file with all the environment variables replaced...e.g. say the environment variable $HOSTNAME is 'myhost' and $unconfigured is not set, a script should produce the following output:

```
HOST_URL=http://myhost
STD_CONFIG=http://myhost/config
USER_CONFIG=http://myhost/config/
```

I was thinking this could be done in a simple one-liner with some sort of sed/awk magic, but I'm no expert and my searches have been in vein, so appreciate any help.

Edit:

I should mention that the file can really be any format text file, for example xml. I just want to replace anything that looks like an env variable with whatever is currently set in the environment.

Comment: You should consider accepting the correct answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed 's/$HOSTNAME/myhost/g;s/$unconfigured//g' yourfile.txt > another_file.txt
```

#### update:

Based on updates in your question, this won't be a good solution.

#### update2 :

This is based on an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914220/bash-templating-how-to-build-configuration-files-from-templates-with-bash/2916159#2916159). I've hacked at it (I'm unfamiliar with perl) to remove undefined vars.

```
perl -p -e 's/\$\{([^}]+)\}/defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&/eg; s/\$\{([^}]+)\}//eg' yourfile.txt
```

Should work for any input text file, however you will need to define vars using the `${...}` format which simplifies the string matching.

(*rant regarding the evilness of eval moved to a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274343/replacing-environment-variables-in-a-properties-file/5274922#5274922) so as not to confuse readers*)

Comment: Or more readable (IMHO): `sed -e 's/$HOSTNAME/myhost/' -e 's/$unconfigured//` ...

Comment: Assuming I know the env variables used within the config files I could use this technique, but I really want something more generic.

Comment: @Shawn-Chin Thanks! I'll probably use this as I like the `${}` style of using properties.

Comment: I think the perl command can be simplified to `perl -p -e 's/\$\{([^}]+)\}/defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : ""/eg' yourfile.txt` based on comments on the related question, instead of having a 2nd regex to remove empty variables.  You simply need to replace `$&` with `""`

Comment: @JoelPearson's regex has the advantage of not removing backslash

Answer (score 190):

This is what `envsubst` is for.

```
echo 'Hello $USER'
Hello $USER
echo 'Hello $USER' | envsubst
Hello malvineous
```

You would probably use it more like this though:

```
envsubst < input.txt > output.txt
```

`envsubst` seems to be part of GNU gettext.

Comment: This seems to be the only really correct answer here. Should be marked up higher.

Comment: I would just like to say thanks for this answer. My friend and I were struggling with sed, awk and other "tricks" and this answer saved us. Knowledge is power. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

*"eval is evil"*

This is not an answer, but a warning in response to [using eval for this task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274343/replacing-environment-variables-in-a-properties-file/5274670#5274670). You *really really really* don't want to do that.

**Exhibit 1: a malicious template file:**

```
HOST_URL=http://$HOSTNAME
STD_CONFIG=http://$HOSTNAME/config
USER_CONFIG=http://$HOSTNAME/config/$unconfigured
&& cat /etc/redhat-release
```

**An unsuspecting user:**

```
[lsc@aphek]$ cat somefile | while read line; do echo $(eval echo `echo $line`); done
HOST_URL=http://xyz
STD_CONFIG=http://xyz/config
USER_CONFIG=http://xyz/config/
Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 9)
```

**Note the last line!**

Now, imagine the possibilities....

Comment: this came to mind too. i was surprised people considered that. there should be a substitution mechanism in bash, really! or else, we should write a standard tool for this.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it like this:

```
# Set the $HOSTNAME and other variables
# Now evaluate the properties file as a shell script.
. config.properties
# Write the values
cat >somefile <<EOF
HOST_URL=$HOST_URL
STD_CONFIG=$STD_CONFIG
USER_CONFIG=$USER_CONFIG
EOF
```

**Edit**: Or this very nasty thing (I'm sure there's a better way)

```
for name in HOST_URL STD_CONFIG USER_CONFIG
    echo "$name=$(eval echo `echo '$'$name`)" >>somefile
end
```

Comment: I can't assume the file is a valid shell script (just name=value) - it might be any format, for example xml.

Comment: @Andy Whitfield: Too bad :-) Then you're off to awk/sed.

Comment: Your edit gave my an idea: this little nugget: `cat somefile | while read line; do echo $(eval echo `echo $line`); done`

Comment: The formatting doesn't come out too well in the comment here, so I'll paste it as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @DarkDust I came up with this:

```
cat somefile | while read line; do echo $(eval echo `echo $line`); done > somefile.replaced
```

Comment: And even a one-liner ;-) Now that looks like a solution, as long as you know that your input files will not have `$` except for variables.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T USE THAT. Pardon the raised voice, but this is one situation where screaming is warranted. See explanation in my answer.

Comment: @Shawn No probs - thanks for the warning. I'm going with the perl line - works like a charm.

Comment: I was more worried about unsuspecting user that may come across it in the future. Posted warning as a separate item so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: This will omit spaces at the beginning of lines and also lines containing `#`.

Answer (score 2):

I used this oneliner to replace `${VARIABLE}` style variables in a file:

```
TARGET_FILE=/etc/apache2/apache2.conf; for VARNAME in $(grep -P -o -e '\$\{\S+\}' ${TARGET_FILE} | sed -e 's|^\${||g' -e 's|}$||g' | sort -u); do sed -i "s|\${$(echo $VARNAME)}|${!VARNAME}|g" ${TARGET_FILE}; done
```

I'm pretty sure someone can do this in 1/3rd of the length using `awk`… feel challenged! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of Javascript that I like to have around for solving this exact problem:

```
// A Javascript version of envsubst for our builds
// Purpose: replace all ocurrences of ${VAR} with the equivalent var from the environment from stdin
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

const environment = process.env;

rl.on('line', function(line) {
  const newLine = line.replace(/\$\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\}/g, function(_match, variable) {
    const envVar = environment[variable];
    return envVar ? envVar : '';
  });

  process.stdout.write(`${newLine}\n`);
});
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short one-liner that uses python's curly brace formatting to safely do the magic:

```
contents=\"\"\"`cat $file`\"\"\"; python -c "import os;print $contents.format(**os.environ)"
```

- avoids evil eval
- allows outputting curly braces: use `{{` instead of `{`
- no need to specify vars explicitly when calling the script

For example, given properties file `settings.properties`:

```
# my properties file
someVar = {MY_ENV_VAR}
curlyBraceVar = has {{curly braces}}
```

Then, do the substitution with:

```
$ export MY_ENV_VAR="hello"
$ file=settings.properties 
$ contents=\"\"\"`cat $file`\"\"\"; python  -c "import os;print $contents.format(**os.environ)"
# my properties file
someVar = hello
curlyBraceVar = has {curly braces}
```

A script is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aneilbaboo/machome/master/bin/substenv

Comment: This does not avoid evil eval, it just obfuscates it.  `echo '"""; print "arbitrary code execution"; """' > ~/myfile;`  creates a file that causes some arbitrary code to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed nodejs you can run

```sh
npx @utft/tt -e FOO=bar /path/to/input /path/to/output
```

or you can run it programmatically
https://github.com/utftufutukgyftryidytftuv/tt