# how to replace a variable in shell script string

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having problems getting this to work...

I have a variable that is holding a SQL to with a placeholder:

```
echo $SQL
SELECT PX_PROMOTION_ID, PRIORITY, STATUS, EXCLSVE, TYPE, PERORDLMT, PERSHOPPERLMT, TOTALLMT, RSV_INT, PX_GROUP_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, STOREENT_ID, VERSION, REVISION, EFFECTIVE, TRANSFER, CDREQUIRED, EXPIRE, LASTUPDATEBY, TO_CHAR(LASTUPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS LASTUPDATE, TO_CHAR(STARTDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS STARTDATE, TO_CHAR(ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS ENDDATE, TO_CHAR(RSV_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS RSV_TIME, RSV_REAL, TGTSALES, NAME, CODE, RSV_VCH, OPTCOUNTER FROM PX_PROMOTION WHERE LASTUPDATE BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(BATCHSTART) FROM XRPTEBATCHCONTROL) AND TIMESTAMP('$BATCH_END')
```

I have another variable that holds the value:

```
echo $BATCH_END
2012-11-14 17:06:13
```

I want to replace the placeholder with the value. I'm not particularly great at Unix scripting, but I've tried this:

```
echo $SQL | sed -e "s/'$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g"
```

but it still doesn't get replaced...

Can anyone help? I want to replace the placeholder, and keep the final string assigned to $SQL

I also need to know how to get the value of the output back into the variable, for example, I tried:

```
 SQL=`echo "$SQL" | echo "${SQL//\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END}"`
```

Comment: Too much echo. Use `SQL="${SQL//\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END}"` instead

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2914220/619001) is a more general version of this question, covering replacement of all variables without knowing in advance what the variables will be named.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are missing the end of that single-quote pair in your script.

Change from:

```
echo $SQL | sed -e "s/'$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g"
```

To:

```
echo $SQL | sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g"
```

**Updated** - as per followup comment:

To save the result of the above replacement back into `$SQL`, do either of the following:

```
# Preferred way
SQL=$(echo $SQL | sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g")

# Old way
SQL=`echo $SQL | sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g"`
```

This is called [**command substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Either syntax (`$(...)` vs. enclosure by backticks) works, but the preferred one allows you to do nesting.

**The *preferred*-preferred way: [Herestring](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17700.html)**

This is probably a bit more advanced than what you care about, but doing it in the following way will save you a subprocess from having to use `echo` unnecessarily:

```
SQL=$(sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g" <<< $SQL)
```

Comment: The replacement value still needs quotes around it.

Comment: ok I got this far:SQL=echo $SQL | sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/g", but the assignment back is not working although the SED seems to be now. How do I assign it back to the SQL variable?

Comment: @RichardG See my updated answer for assigning the replaced result back into the SQL variable, I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In my terminal:

```
$ SQL="SELECT PX_PROMOTION_ID, PRIORITY, STATUS, EXCLSVE, TYPE, PERORDLMT, PERSHOPPERLMT, TOTALLMT, RSV_INT, PX_GROUP_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, STOREENT_ID, VERSION, REVISION, EFFECTIVE, TRANSFER, CDREQUIRED, EXPIRE, LASTUPDATEBY, TO_CHAR(LASTUPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS LASTUPDATE, TO_CHAR(STARTDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS STARTDATE, TO_CHAR(ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS ENDDATE, TO_CHAR(RSV_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS RSV_TIME, RSV_REAL, TGTSALES, NAME, CODE, RSV_VCH, OPTCOUNTER FROM PX_PROMOTION WHERE LASTUPDATE BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(BATCHSTART) FROM XRPTEBATCHCONTROL) AND TIMESTAMP('\$BATCH_END')"
$ # (observe: I escaped the $ sign to have the same variable as you)
$ echo "$SQL"
SELECT PX_PROMOTION_ID, PRIORITY, STATUS, EXCLSVE, TYPE, PERORDLMT, PERSHOPPERLMT, TOTALLMT, RSV_INT, PX_GROUP_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, STOREENT_ID, VERSION, REVISION, EFFECTIVE, TRANSFER, CDREQUIRED, EXPIRE, LASTUPDATEBY, TO_CHAR(LASTUPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS LASTUPDATE, TO_CHAR(STARTDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS STARTDATE, TO_CHAR(ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS ENDDATE, TO_CHAR(RSV_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS RSV_TIME, RSV_REAL, TGTSALES, NAME, CODE, RSV_VCH, OPTCOUNTER FROM PX_PROMOTION WHERE LASTUPDATE BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(BATCHSTART) FROM XRPTEBATCHCONTROL) AND TIMESTAMP('$BATCH_END')
$ BATCH_END="2012-11-14 17:06:13"
$ echo "$BATCH_END"
2012-11-14 17:06:13
$ # Now the replacement:
$ echo "${SQL//\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END}"
SELECT PX_PROMOTION_ID, PRIORITY, STATUS, EXCLSVE, TYPE, PERORDLMT, PERSHOPPERLMT, TOTALLMT, RSV_INT, PX_GROUP_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, STOREENT_ID, VERSION, REVISION, EFFECTIVE, TRANSFER, CDREQUIRED, EXPIRE, LASTUPDATEBY, TO_CHAR(LASTUPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS LASTUPDATE, TO_CHAR(STARTDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS STARTDATE, TO_CHAR(ENDDATE, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS ENDDATE, TO_CHAR(RSV_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD HH24MMSS') AS RSV_TIME, RSV_REAL, TGTSALES, NAME, CODE, RSV_VCH, OPTCOUNTER FROM PX_PROMOTION WHERE LASTUPDATE BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(BATCHSTART) FROM XRPTEBATCHCONTROL) AND TIMESTAMP('2012-11-14 17:06:13')
```

Done!

Comment: ok that's a neat approach rather than SED, but how do I get it assigned back to the SQL variable,  tried:  SQL=`echo "${SQL//\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END}"`

Comment: You should be able to use: `SQL=${SQL//\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END}` just like that. You might need double quotes around the RHS of the assigment in some shells, but not in `bash` (and only `bash`, AFAIK, supports the `//` modifier on parameter expansion — though it wouldn't surprise me to find that `zsh` does too).

Comment: Great listing all used commands! Helped to understand what's going on.

Comment: how can the same be achieved in ksh. the same script says bad substitution

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the first `$` so that it does not get expanded as a shell variable.

```
echo "$SQL" | sed -e "s/'\$BATCH_END'/'$BATCH_END'/g"
```

… Or choose an easier placeholder, something like `@BATCH_END@` for instance.

To assign the result back to `$SQL` you will need some more shell escaping:

```
SQL=`echo "$SQL" | sed -e "s/'\\\$BATCH_END'/'$BATCH_END'/g"`
```

Comment: Strongly recommend `SQL=$(...)` over ``SQL=`...` ``.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with 'differential quoting' in a single argument:

```
echo "$SQL" | sed -e 's/$BATCH_END/'"$BATCH_END/g"
```

The first part of the `-e` option is in single quotes, so the shell does not expand the first `$BATCH_END` and it can match the word in the SQL statement.  The second part is in double quotes, so the shell expands the second `$BATCH_END` and places its text into the SQL.

If you needed to worry about the single quotes around `$BATCH_END`, you'd have to play other tricks; probably a backslash would be simplest (and it's a viable option anyway):

```
echo "$SQL" | sed -e "s/'\$BATCH_END'/'$BATCH_END'/g"
```

The backslash stops the shell expanding the first `$BATCH_END` but the absence of a backslash means the second is expanded.  Inside the double quotes, the single quotes lose their 'no expansion' property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a double-quoted string in the shell. In a double quoted string, variables like `$BATCH_END` get interpreted as shell variables and interpolated. The `'` character has no special meaning within a double quoted string; it doesn't prevent variables from being interpolated. So your `$BATCH_END` string is being substituted in both places; your `sed` invocation is equivalent to:

```
sed -e "s/'2012-11-14 17:06:13/2012-11-14 17:06:13/"
```

Which as you can see, is not very helpful (you also have a stray `'` in there). You need to escape the `$` sign, to prevent it from being interpreted as a shell variable:

```
sed -e "s/\$BATCH_END/$BATCH_END/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Situation to add 80% memory in "maxmemory" in redis.conf:

```sh
# GET TOTAL MEMORY
totalmemory=$(awk '{ printf "%.2f", $2/1024 ; exit}' /proc/meminfo | awk -F"." '{print $1}');

# CALCUL
ramredis=$(echo $totalmemory/100*80 | bc);

# APPLY
sed -i 's/#maxmemory/maxmemory x mb/g' /etc/redis.conf;sed -i 's/ x /'\ $ramredis'/g' /etc/redis.conf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote

```
sed -i "s/targetString/$newName/g" targetFile.toml
```