# Substitute environment variables in NGINX config from docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to start an NGINX server within a docker container configured through docker-compose. The catch is, however, that I would like to substitute an environment variable inside of the http section, specifically within the "upstream" block.

It would be awesome to have this working, because I have several other containers that are all configured through environment variables, and I have about 5 environments that need to be running at any given time. I have tried using "envsubst" (as suggested by the official NGINX docs), perl_set, and set_by_lua, however none of them appear to be working.

Below is the NGINX config, as it is after my most recent trial

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
env NGINXPROXY;

load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    perl_set $nginxproxy 'sub { return $ENV{"NGINXPROXY"}; }';

    upstream api-upstream {
        server ${nginxproxy};
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Below is the NGINX dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.17.0-perl
COPY --from=0 /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
RUN mkdir /certs
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Below is the section of the docker-compose.yml for the NGINX server (with names and IPs changed). The envsubst command is intentionally commented out at this point in my troubleshooting.

```
front-end:
        environment:
            - NGINXPROXY=172.31.67.100:9300
        build: http://gitaccount:password@gitserver.com/group/front-end.git#develop
        container_name: qa_front_end
        image: qa-front-end
        restart: always
        networks:
            qa_network:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.0.215
        ports:
            - "9080:80"
        # command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$NGINXPROXY' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

What appears to be happening is when I reference the $nginxproxy variable in the upstream block (right after "server"), I get output that makes it look like it's referencing the string literal "$nginxproxy" rather than substituting the value of the variable.

```
qa3_front_end       | 2019/06/18 12:35:36 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "${nginx_upstream}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
qa3_front_end       | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "${nginx_upstream}" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:19
qa3_front_end exited with code 1
```

When I attempt to use envsubst, I get an error that makes it sound like the command messed with the format of the nginx.conf file

```
qa3_front_end       | 2019/06/18 12:49:02 [emerg] 1#1: no "events" section in configuration
qa3_front_end       | nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
qa3_front_end exited with code 1
```

I'm pretty stuck, so thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So after some wrestling with this issue, I managed to get it working similarly to the answer provided by bellackn. I am going to post my exact solution here, in case anybody else needs to reference a complete solution.

Step1: Write your nginx.conf or default.conf how you would normally write it. Save the file as "nginx.conf.template", or "default.conf.template" depending on which you are trying to substitute variables into.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream api-upstream {
        server 192.168.25.254;
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Step2: Substitute a variable in the format ${VARNAME} for whatever value(s) you want to replace with an environment variable:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream api-upstream {
        server ${SERVER_NAME};
    }

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Step 3: In your docker-file, copy your nginx configuration files (your nginx.conf.template or default.conf.template) into your container at the appropriate location:

```
# build stage
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.17.0-perl
COPY --from=0 /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gettext-base
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
#-----------------------------------#
|COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d|
|COPY nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx|
#-----------------------------------#
RUN mkdir /certs
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Step 4: Set your environment variable in your docker-compos.yml file using the "environment" section label. Make sure your environment variable name matches whatever variable name you chose within your nginx config file. Use the "envsubt" command within your docker container to substitute your variable values in for your variables within your nginx.conf.template, and write the output to a file named nginx.conf in the correct location. This can be done within the docker-compose.yml file by using the "command" section label:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    front-end:
        environment:
            - SERVER_NAME=172.31.67.100:9100
        build: http://git-account:git-password@git-server.com/project-group/repository-name.git#branch-ame
        container_name: qa_front_end
        image: qa-front-end-vue
        restart: always
        networks:
            qa_network:
                ipv4_address: 172.28.0.215
        ports:
            - "9080:80"
        command: >
            /bin/sh -c
            "envsubst '
            $${SERVER_NAME}
            '< /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template
            > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

Step 5: Run your stack with docker-compose up (with whatever additional switches you need) and your nginx server should now start with whatever value you supplied in the "environment" section of your docker-compose.yml

As mentioned in the solution above, you can also define your own entry point, however this solution has also proven to work pretty well, and keeps everything contained into a single configuration file, giving me the ability to run a stack of services directly from git with nothing but a docker-compose.yml file.

A big thank you to everybody who took the time to ready through this, and bellackn for taking the time to help me solve the issue.

Comment: I get this error: ` ERROR: Service 'server' failed to build: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat nginx.conf.template: file does not exist `. And I have tried many ways to save nginx.conf.template and I checked this file into container, it existed. What docker-compose configurations do I need to use?

Comment: I would take a look at bellackn's answer. It's a much simpler setup than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 52):

[Since nginx 1.19](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) you can now use environment variables in your configuration with docker-compose.  I used the following setup:

```
# file: docker/nginx/templates/default.conf.conf
upstream api-upstream {
    server ${API_HOST};
}


# file: docker-compose.yml
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.19-alpine
        volumes:
            - "./docker/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates/"
        environment:
            NGINX_ENVSUBST_TEMPLATE_SUFFIX: ".conf"
            API_HOST: api.example.com
```

I'm going off script a little from the example in the documentation.  Note the extra `.conf` extension on the template file - this is not a typo.  In the docs for the nginx image it is suggested to name the file, for example, `default.conf.template`.  Upon startup, a script will take that file, substitute the environment variables, and then output the file to /etc/nginx/conf.d/ with the original file name, dropping the `.template` suffix.

By default that suffix is `.template`, but this breaks syntax highlighting unless you configure your editor.  Instead, I specified `.conf` as the template suffix.  If you only name your file `default.conf` the result will be a file named /etc/nginx/conf.d/default and your site won't be served as expected.

Comment: Just a quick clarifying point: this file needs to be in the templates directory of the nginx container.  If you were using a `./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/` docker compose volume to manage this file, you'll need to change it to `./docker/nginx/templates/:/etc/nginx/templates/` instead

Comment: @JosephMarikle good idea, i've updated the example to reflect your comment

Comment: Do I need to copy the template files manually into /etc/nginx/templates? I am following this setup but it is not copying into templates. My templates folder is empty.

Comment: in this example, you have a docker-compose.yml in a folder with a ./docker/nginx/templates/ containing your templates relative to that on your host.

Comment: Honestly this is great. I wish this worked when I was setting this up.

Comment: If you're committing your `docker-compose.yml` to revision control and want to use a separate untracked `.env` file to maintain environment-specific variables, docker-compose will substitute your `.env` variables into `docker-compose.yml` before it starts your containers. So `docker-compose.yml` can specify the environment variable as `API_HOST: ${API_HOST}`, while `.env` can set the actual value: `API_HOST=api.example.com`. May be obvious to docker-compose experts, but took me hours to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `.template` gets removed _retaining_ the rest of the file name, which naturally _needs the .conf_ extension. I've solved the naming of the original file by keeping my `whatever.conf` file and then in the Dockerfile section for nginx I've used `COPY whatever.conf /etc/nginx/templates/whatever.conf.template`, saves you the extra volume hanging around but is a bit more opaque.

Answer (score 13):

You can avoid some of the hassles with Compose interpreting environment variables by defining your own entrypoint. See this simple example:

- entrypoint.sh (make sure this file is executable)

```
#!/bin/sh

export NGINXPROXY

envsubst '${NGINXPROXY}' < /config.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

exec "$@"
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    front-end:
        image: nginx
        environment:
            - NGINXPROXY=172.31.67.100:9300
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./config:/config.template
            - ./entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
        entrypoint: ["/entrypoint.sh"]
        command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My `config` file has the same content as your `nginx.conf`, aside from the fact that I had to comment the lines using the Perl module.

Note that I had to mount my config file to another location before I could `envsubst` it. I encountered some strange behaviour in the form that the file ends up empty after the substitution, which can be avoided by this approach. It shouldn't be a problem in your specific case, because you already embed it in your image on build time.

---

**EDIT**

For completeness, to change your setup as little as possible, you just have to make sure that you `export` your environment variable. Adapt your command like this:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "export NGINXPROXY && envsubst '$$NGINXPROXY' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

...and you should be good to go. I would always recommend the "cleaner" way with defining your own entrypoint, though.

Comment: I might `COPY` this script in the Dockerfile and specify it as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`, rather than overriding it only at runtime.

Answer (score 9):

Like already [explained in Jody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649582/substitute-environment-variables-in-nginx-config-from-docker-compose/62844707#62844707), nowadays the official Nginx Docker image supports parsing templates. This uses `envsubst` and [its handling](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh) ensures not to mess with [Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html) such as `$host` and all. Nice. However, `envsubst` does not support default values like a regular shell and Docker Compose do when using `${MY_VAR:-My Default}`. So, this built-in templating would always need a full setup of all variables, even when using the defaults.

To define defaults in the image itself, one can use a custom entry point to first set the defaults and then simply delegate to [the original entrypoint](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh). Like a `docker-defaults.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -eu

# As of version 1.19, the official Nginx Docker image supports templates with
# variable substitution. But that uses `envsubst`, which does not allow for
# defaults for missing variables. Here, first use the regular command shell
# to set the defaults:
export PROXY_API_DEST=${PROXY_API_DEST:-http://host.docker.internal:8000/api/}

# Due to `set -u` this would fail if not defined and no default was set above
echo "Will proxy requests for /api/* to ${PROXY_API_DEST}*"

# Finally, let the original Nginx entry point do its work, passing whatever is
# set for CMD. Use `exec` to replace the current process, to trap any signals
# (like Ctrl+C) that Docker may send it:
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

Along with, say, some `docker-nginx-default.conf`:

```
# After variable substitution, this will replace /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api/ {
       # Proxy API calls to another destination; the default for the variable is
       # set in docker-defaults.sh
       proxy_pass $PROXY_API_DEST;
    }
}
```

In the Dockerfile copy the template into `/etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template` and set the custom entry point:

```sh
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

...

# Each time Nginx is started it will perform variable substition in all template
# files found in `/etc/nginx/templates/*.template`, and copy the results (without
# the `.template` suffix) into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. Below, this will replace the
# original `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`; see https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx
COPY docker-nginx-default.conf /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
COPY docker-defaults.sh /
# Just in case the file mode was not properly set in Git
RUN chmod +x /docker-defaults.sh

# This will delegate to the original Nginx `docker-entrypoint.sh`
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-defaults.sh"]

# The default parameters to ENTRYPOINT (unless overruled on the command line)
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now using, e.g., `docker run --env PROXY_API_DEST=https://example.com/api/ ...` will set a value, which in this example will default to `http://host.docker.internal:8000/api/` if not set (which is actually  `http://localhost:8000/api/` on the local machine).

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx
section "Using environment variables in nginx configuration (new in 1.19)"
you can use environment variables.

But it's does not work due to bug inside docker container script:
https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/entrypoint/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh#L25

running this script always fails with error:
**/docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: line 25: 3: Bad file descriptor**

I created issue https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/645
and pull request https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/pull/646

As workaround for now I copied this script and change it locally/

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a more advanced nginx docker image. For example [nginx4docker](https://github.com/MarkusGnigler/nginx4docker), it implements a bunch of basic env variables that can be set through docker and you don't have to fiddle around with nginx basic templating and all it's drawbacks.

nginx4docker could also be extended with your custom env variables. only mount a file that lists all your env variables to docker `... --mount $(pwd)/CUSTOM_ENV:/ENV ...`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is coping entrypoint sh file into /docker-entrypoint.d directory of nginx container. As mentioned above, you need to copy *.template* file. But you dont need to create two seperate files.

1. Copy the file config file with temporary name in Dockerfile. But it's important to **not use ENTRYPOINT** command in Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx 
...
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.temp
```

2. create an sh file named `05-docker-entrypoint.sh` in your project directory (host) and put the following code into the sh file as mentioned above

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -eu
envsubst '${MY_VARIABLE}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.temp > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
exec "$@"
```

3. Mount `05-docker-entrypoint.sh` using docker-compose.yml file to /docker-entrypoint.d directory of nginx container or copy it using Dockerfile. This two options are looking like this :

Option 1. (i prefer this)  Mounting file using compose file :

```
 web:
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      - MY_VARIABLE=blabala
    volumes:
      - ./05-docker-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/05-docker-entrypoint.sh
    ....
```

Option 2.
Use Dockerfile to copy files into container

Final Dockerfile with Option2 looks like :

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.temp 
COPY ./05-docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.d/05-docker-entrypoint.sh
```