# Include docker compose startup command in Dockerfile or docker run

Tags: shell, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using following command in docker-compose to copy environment values into nginx configuration file at startup of nginx container.

```
command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

I want to get rid of docker-compose and use it with the docker run. I tried to inlcude the command in Dockerfile and use CMD. But the ngix container immediately exit.

```
FROM mydocker:latest
COPY ./site.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template

CMD envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Can someone please help me here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So why not `CMD /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/site.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"`? What is your entrypoint?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651109/10008173) shows an entrypoint-oriented approach to the same problem; it's a little more focused on a Compose-only setup but it's pretty easy to translate that to Dockerfile syntax.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks mate. I that answer helped and it works now. thanks you too.