# How to create dynamic env variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Docker composé ver 1.5 or 6 and nginx image. I want to parameterize the nginx.config. To do that I want to create a var from $(basename some path). But the problem is Docker does not accept dynamic vars like that in env part of the Dockerfile. Another problem is that I also cannot map those variables on build run as Docker compose does not accept dynamic, scripted vars. How to overcome that issue?

```
From nginx
ENV myvar=$(basename /)
```

This is impossible to build the image.

The other way was

```
ARG myvar
ENV myvar2=myvar
```

But my version of Docker compose allows only to set

```
Environment: myvar=$(basename mypathinthevolume/)
```

That also does not seem to work

Comment: please, give us more information, paste your dockerfile and docker-compose at least

Comment: Have you looked at techniques like what's described in [Substitute environment variables in NGINX config from docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649582/substitute-environment-variables-in-nginx-config-from-docker-compose)?  If you create a template configuration and then rewrite it in your image's entrypoint, you can substitute content however you want.

Comment: In the particular example of `$(basename /some/path)`, typically the filesystem layout of a Docker container is fixed and it's okay to hard-code paths there.  If you're bind-mounting host content, require the container-side path to be _e.g._ `/data`.

Comment: @David Maze that's the problem. I can't use static paths as the volume contents differ and I need the name in configuration.

Comment: Another thing - I cannot use the nginx base image. I use FROM nginx so in effect I cannot map the variable in the same line/container as nginx is executed.