# How to pass IP form a docker container to another container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose and one service runs NGINX. Inside its configuration I need the IP address of another service/container. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649582/substitute-environment-variables-in-nginx-config-from-docker-compose) which describes how to use env variables in nginx config files. However, the problem I have now is how to get an IP address of a service inside another service?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webserver: 
  environments:
     - API_HOST: api
  ...

  api: 
    ...
```

This is what I tried, but this will not result in an environment variable with an IP address. The contents of the $API_HOST will just be `api`.

So my question is, how can I do this. In that post I mention above there is also a solution to have a custom entrypoint script, so I can execute commands on startup inside the nginx container! Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use the service name in your nginx config? Docker should resolve the name to the container IP. However, if you definitely need the IP, you can assign your api service a static IP and pass it as environment variable

Comment: I tried to use the service name, but nginx didn't like that. But maybe you're right with using a static ip. Thnx for the suggestion!

Comment: Steps on how tos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose

Comment: Weird, that the service name did not work. I have also used nginx with `docker-compose` and haven't had a problem. Maybe you can post your nginx problem as a separate question.

Comment: Yes it can indeed work, for example, this works: ` proxy_pass http://api:3000;` but this doesn't: `allow api;`

Comment: I see, I guess as a workaround you could allow `172.18.0.0/16` which is all containers in the network

Comment: haha, that is exactly what I'm trying out right now. I noticed that the network uses 172.0.0.0/8. Just to be on the safe side! Using static ip addresses works too btw. I followed the steps from the link from @SuchandraT . But is not an ideal solution for me. Thanks a lot!