# Access Elastic Beanstalk environment properties in NGINX configs running on AWS Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I had this working before on AWS Linux AMI but no luck with AWS Linux 2.

I need to access my environment properties from the Nginx configuration file during the EB application deployment. It's a Single instance Node Server.

I did it like this with the AWS Linux AMI and it worked without a problem:

.ebextensions/00_options.config

```
option_settings:
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
      DOMAIN: socket.example.com
      MASTER_DOMAIN: https://example.com
      etc..
```

.ebextensions/10_proxy.config

```
... some configs ...

files:

  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |

      upstream nodejs {
          server 127.0.0.1:8081;
          keepalive 256;
      }

      map $http_origin $cors_header {
          hostnames;
          default "";
          `{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "OptionName": "MASTER_DOMAIN"}}` "$http_origin";
      }

      server {

          listen 80;
          listen 8080;

          server_name `{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "OptionName": "DOMAIN"}}`;

          location ~ /.well-known {
              allow all;
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
          }
          location / {
              return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
          }
      }
      
      etc..


.... some more configs ....
```

I'm not including most of the configs above because they're not relevant.

So when I did this before, everything worked as expected. The config file inserted my properties and created the file in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` folder.

---

Now with AWS Linux 2 the specs have changed and we have to add our Nginx configuration files in the `.platform/nginx/conf.d` folder located in our application bundle root folder.

[Here the reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) ( see **Reverse proxy configuration**)

So I created a `proxy.conf` file in the location mentioned above with the content that was previously inserted in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

---

.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}
    
map $http_origin $cors_header {
    hostnames;
    default "";
   `{"Fn::GetOptionSetting": {"Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "OptionName": "MASTER_DOMAIN"}}` "$http_origin";
}

etc...
```

And then the problems began..

This first trial throwed `unexpected "{" in /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:11` at me.

And after that I tried a lot of things. Tried it with `${MASTER_DOMAIN}` and messed around with the new EB AWS Linux 2 `hooks` (see link above **Platform hooks**). All for no avail it seems like you can't access the properties from the Nginx configs. I've read an article or a documentation from Nginx mentioning something similar today but I can't find it anymore (did a lot of googling).

---

I also tried to create a config file like I did with the working version which purpose was to save a temp file somewhere with the included properties and then include this file in the needed `.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` file because I started to think that there is no way to include them directly with the new specs.

.ebextensions/10_proxy.config

```
... some configs ....

files:

  /var/proxy/staging/custom_folder/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
    
    etc...
```

.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf

```
include custom_folder/proxy.conf;
```

With this idea in mind I did a lot of nonsense, I created `hooks` for creating (`mkdir`) directories in which I tried to temporarily save the file which leaded to new permission errors. I wasn't able to give the proper permissions to `prebuild`, `postdeploy` files but this is another issue.

And a lot more of trying and failing...

---

But then I've read (also from the link above):

"*If you configure your proxy to send traffic to multiple application processes, you can configure several **environment properties**, and use their values in both **proxy configuration** and your application code.*"

And hope came back.. Does this mean I actually **CAN** directly add environmental variables into the Nginx configs located in the `.platform` directory? ... I don't know.. Do you?

---

I could continue to describe all the things I tried all night long so I will stop here. I hope you get the issue. If not ask me and I will do my best to make all this understandable.

Also my mind isn't very clear anymore after 14 hours of battling this issue. I need a break.

If you did it to the end thank you for your time and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

### Summary

One way to do it is to create a shell script in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy`.

Here is a simplified example, assuming you have an Elastic Beanstalk environment property called `MASTER_DOMAIN`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
# write nginx config file
cat > /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/test.conf << LIMIT_STRING
location /test/ {
  default_type text/html;
  return 200 "nginx variable: \$host, and EB env property: $MASTER_DOMAIN";
}
LIMIT_STRING
    
# restart nginx service so the config takes effect
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

The `location` block from this example can be replaced by the nginx `content` from `.ebextensions/10_proxy.config` in the original post. No need for the `Fn::GetOptionSetting` stuff though.

I think you also need a duplicate script in `.platform/confighooks/postdeploy`.

Details below.

(sorry for the wall of text)

### Environment variables in nginx

Actually, as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21866477) and [here](https://serverfault.com/q/577370), it is not possible (*out-of-the-box*) to use os environment variables inside the `http`, `server`, or `location` blocks in nginx config files. There are some workarounds, such as using lua, perl, or templates, but let's not get into those. This part has nothing to do with AWS.

In the OP's original configuration for Amazon Linux AMI (AL1), using the `files` section in `.ebextensions/10_proxy.config`, they were actually using a shell script to write the nginx config file during deployment. The shell script expanded the environment variables, but the resulting `proxy.conf` for nginx did not actually access any environment variables.

That's why it worked on AL1.

### Platform hooks

Now, for Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), we can do something similar using shell scripts in the `.platform/hooks` and `.platform/confighooks` folders.

These `.platform` hook scripts are executed as the `root` user, and they have access to the Elastic Beanstalk (EB) environment properties. The EB environment properties can be accessed just like normal OS environment variables, so there is no need to use the `Fn::GetOptionSetting` stuff.

Basically, we need to create a shell script that writes a file with the `content` from your original `.ebextensions/10_proxy.config`. However, there are two questions we need to consider:

1. Should we use a `prebuild`, `predeploy`, or `postdeploy` hook?
2. What is the proper destination directory for our nginx `proxy.conf` file?

### File locations

To answer these questions, we have to refer to the AWS documentation for [Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), and specifically the [Instance deployment workflow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.workflow) section.

> ... The current working directory (cwd) for platform hooks is the application's root directory. For prebuild and predeploy files it's the application staging directory, and for postdeploy files it's the current application directory. If one of the files fails (exits with a non-zero exit code), the deployment aborts and fails.

This is interesting, but leaves some questions, e.g. where is the "application staging directory" located? We can fill in the blanks by inspecting one of our deployment log files. Based on our `eb-engine.log`, here's what happens with the platform hooks and nginx config files during app deployment (skipping a lot of details):

1. the source bundle is downloaded from S3 and extracted to `/var/app/staging/`
2. platform hooks in `.platform/hooks/prebuild/` are executed
3. proxy server configuration is copied from `/var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/` to `/var/proxy/staging/nginx`
4. platform hooks in `.platform/hooks/predeploy/` are executed
5. proxy server is started, configuration is copied from `/var/proxy/staging/nginx/` to `/etc/nginx`
6. platform hooks in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/` are executed

Note, after deployment the app is located in `/var/app/current`.

Based on the above, there are several options:

1. Create a shell script in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy` that writes to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

   The nginx service is already running, at this stage, so we need to restart for the configuration to take effect.

   Below is a minimal test example. In this example we write to the `elasticbeanstalk` subdirectory, because we just want to add a `location` inside the default `server` block. We can then visit the `/test/` page in a browser, to check that the configuration works.

   We use some [bash io redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) (`<<`, `>`) to write the nginx config file.

   Note that we need to escape any nginx variables, e.g. `$host` becomes `\$host`, otherwise the shell will interpret them as environment variables.

   Also note that the shell scripts need to have execution permission, as explained under [More about platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.hooks.more) in the docs.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
cat > /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/test.conf << LIMIT_STRING
location /test/ {
  default_type text/html
  return 200 "nginx variable: \$host, and EB env property: $MASTER_DOMAIN";
}
LIMIT_STRING
    
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

2. Alternatively, we could create a shell script in `.platform/hooks/predeploy` that writes to `/var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

   There is *no need* to restart the nginx service in this case, because this hook is executed before the server configuration is applied.

BEWARE:

Not sure if this is a bug or a design feature, but our newly created `proxy.conf` disappears after a *configuration* deployment (as opposed to an *application* deployment), unless we put a duplicate script in the `.platform/confighooks/postdeploy` directory. Not very DRY...

EDIT: AWS support confirmed that we need duplicate scripts in `hooks` and `confighooks` in this case. The [application example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.example) in the docs also shows some duplicates (at least duplicate filenames) in `hooks` and `confighooks`.

EDIT:
Instead of duplicating scripts, we can also write a confighook that calls a hook, e.g. `.platform/confighooks/predeploy/01_my_confighook.sh` could look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source "/var/app/current/.platform/hooks/predeploy/01_my_hook.sh"
```

Disclaimer: This was tested on a freshly created *single instance* EB environment with "Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.5" using all default configuration and the default AWS Python sample application (only extended with our custom hooks).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer,.I'll try it out when I go back to this issue.