# How fix nginx error "invalid number of arguments"?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i try redirect to proxy-server nginx.

```
        location /phpmyadmin {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass https://${PMA}:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

But i get error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
```

full code for inspect error in this listing, because i'm real can't find some error's (${env} = correctry changing in script

```
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pcre_jit on;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    keepalive_timeout 3000;
    sendfile on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx.key;
        root /home;
        index default.html /default.html;
        location /phpmyadmin {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass https://${PMA}:5000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
        location /wordpress {
            return 307 http://${WP}:5050/;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /default.html default.html default.htm;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
daemon off;
```

how much simvols need for post)

Comment: Which one is on line 26 of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`? Because both look fine to me.

Comment: line. 26 -       proxy_set_header Host      $host;

Comment: You need to inspect that line closely, because it looks ok. The typical cause of that error is a missing `;` on the end of the line. Make sure there are no strange characters in there. Maybe delete the line and retype it.

Comment: added full code

Comment: without line's "proxy_set_header" config working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used envsubst for environment replacing, and this util tried swap $host and other nginx envs, solved with:

```
envsubst '$WP $PMA' < nginx.template.conf > nginx.ready.conf; rm nginx.template.conf
```

This will replace only the `$WP` and `$PMA` variables in the nginx.template.conf file and write the output to nginx.ready.conf. Avoiding a general replacement of all nginx variables like $host, $remote_addr and others. If you dont specify the variables that you want to replace the nginx variables will be replaced with empty values

Comment: Could you please explain your code? You've written file names without explaining which filename is for what. Not everyone finds the code self-explanatory. So a note explaining what it does is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the working answer from @mikhail-prigorodov:

The situation described by the OP arises when using the Nginx Docker container with Docker Compose. In the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), it reads:

> Out-of-the-box, nginx doesn't support environment variables inside most configuration blocks. But this image has a function, which will extract environment variables before nginx starts.

So, if you are using environment variables in your `docker-compose.yml` as part of a [12-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) design, you have to figure out how to get them into your Nginx config file properly.

The solution in the Nginx Docker documentation is to run `envsubst` on a template configuration file and send the output to the Nginx config file. The Dockerfile syntax, which is mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/248) is:

```
CMD envsubst < /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

But that solution runs into a problem if you have Nginx-defined variables **AND** environment variable placeholders in your configuration template. In the directory where I'm building my Nginx container (where my Dockerfile is), I have a `templates` directory with a file called `default.conf.template`, as directed in the documentation. The file contains Nginx variables and environment variables. For example:

```
proxy_set_header Host               $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;

location /static {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/${STATIC_DIR};
}
```

The problem (I think) is that `envsubst` is looking for the "$" character that marks the start of the environment variables. In any case, you'll find that after running `envsubst` successfully, each line in your new Nginx config file that has a Nginx-defined variable (leading "$") in the template gives an error when you try and start Nginx.

To solve this problem, use the syntax provided by @mikhail-prigorodov. Applied to my example:

```
CMD envsubst '\$STATIC_DIR' < /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

This was the solution that worked for me after hours of frustration.

Comment: Thanks for a much more well explained version of Mikhail's answer