# Change apache config file value from bash script

Tags: linux, apache, bash, configuration

I need an example of changing apache configuration values from bash script, so that i can have the same configuration by running the script across my servers instead of copying and pasting the whole config file. Just a starting point to let me figure how could be done.

I've spend the last 2 hours on google but i can't find any clue. Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914220/bash-templating-how-to-build-configuration-files-from-templates-with-bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **sed** command for changing config file of apache for example

```
sed -i "s|\("^ServerRoot" * *\).*|\1/www/www1|" httpd.conf

sed -i "s|\("^Timeout" * *\).*|\1600|" httpd.conf
```

Comment: Sorry, what if i need to comment or uncomment a specific setting in apache2.conf, instead of setting a value? Thanks again!

Comment: for adding # sed -i "^serverRoot/ s/^/# /" httpd.conf

Comment: for removing # sed -i "/${line}/ s/# *//" httpd.conf