# Reading assignments from configuration files

Tags: bash, shell

I have configuration files where each line contains assignments separated by semi-colons.  Something like this, which mimics normal shell assignments :

```
VAR1="1"  ;  VAR2="2"
VAR1="3"  ;  VAR2="4"
```

Each line contains the same variables, and is intended to be processed individually.  These configuration files are all under the system administrator control, so using `eval` to perform the assignment is not too bad for now.  But I would like to extend this to per-user config files, and I am looking for better ideas.

I am able to parse a line, split it in chunks using `;` as a separator (in a way that unfortunately does not allow escaped `;` to be found inside the values, but I can live with that), identify the assignment (valid variable name followed by `=` sign), and extract the right part of the assignment (in raw form, with quoting and spacing as part of the value).  But then I have a problem.

Say I have variable `value` which, after the parsing, contains what would result from a "manual" assignment like this :

```
value="\"Arbitrary value \\\" containing escaped quote inside quotes\""
```

In other words, the value is this (if I `echo "$value"`) :

```
"Arbitrary value \" containing escaped quote inside quotes"
```

I want to transform that value without using `eval` or another method that could cause arbitrary code execution (and therefore code injection risks) so that it becomes this:

```
Arbitrary value " containing escaped quote inside quotes
```

I could, I guess, just look for and remove leading and trailing quotes, but this does not handle all cases of valid shell quoting.  If there is a way to retain safe expansions while preventing code execution, that is a plus, but I am not getting my hopes up with this one.  I would also prefer a Bash-only solution (no external program called), but this is a preference, not a hard requirement.

If I solve that issue, I know how to perform the indirect assignment safely, and I do not need detailed code on how to read files, perform regex matching, etc.  It is only this critical step I am missing, and I hope there is a way that does not involve writing a parser.

Comment: Tangential, but worth pointing out: shell assignments do not need to be separated by a semicolon.

Comment: @kojiro This is true, but I think allowing that in my config files would make parsing more difficult : due to the kind of "dumb" parsing I am doing (which ignores quotes), I cannot differentiate between whitespace inside a quoted value, and trailing whitespace.  Same reason I cannot, with my current approach, embed semi-colons in the values.

Answer (score 2):

One very easy solution is to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). Since "foo is a string \" that contains a quote" is valid json, it handles it natively:

```
$ value="\"Arbitrary value \\\" containing escaped quote inside quotes\""
$ jq -r . <<< "$value"
Arbitrary value " containing escaped quote inside quotes
```

Yes, it's not native sh or bash, but it's a quick and easy solution. Furthermore, jq has methods to output the result back to a format that can be read in by another shell:

```
$ jq -r '.|@sh' <<< "$value"
'Arbitrary value " containing escaped quote inside quotes'
```

Comment: Very simple and readable (not having tested it nor knowing `jq` I cannot vouch for its correctness), but it requires a process/pipe for each and every variable assignment, which I would be willing to trade for a reasonable amount of additional complexity with a Bash-only solution (this is "library" code I will reuse, it does not need to be a one-liner).  `jq` is a utility that (I think) is not part of many Linux/UNIX systems by default (not my systems a least).  Given a choice, I would prefer a `sed` or `awk` solution for that reason, even if not as pleasantly readable as yours.

Comment: I understand. Your later arguments aside, it's worth noting that you could construct your solution with a single jq command to output all the variable assignments in the `@sh` form at once, to avoid having a command or process substitution for every assignment.

Comment: That would be better, but I would still need to do it once per line...  Unless I use a solution which takes the whole file as input, and spits out an array (one element being all the assignments for one line of the config file).  That would be a little more complex, but better on the long run.  Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To complement [kojiro's helpful `jq` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42328057/45375) with a **pure `bash` solution** (a POSIX-compliant implementation is also possible):

```
# Sample value, resulting in the following value, *including* the double quotes:
#     "Arbitrary value \" containing escaped quote inside quotes"
# Note: This is effectively the same assignment as in the question, except
#       with single quotes, which makes it easier to parse visually.
value='"Arbitrary value \" containing escaped quote inside quotes"'    

# Strip enclosing " instances, if present.
[[ $value =~ ^\"(.*)\"$ ]] && value=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# Use `read` - without -r - to perform interpretation of \-prefixed
# escape sequences, and save the result back to $value.
IFS= read value <<<"$value"
```

Running `printf '%s\n' "$value"` afterward yields:

```
Arbitrary value " containing escaped quote inside quotes
```

Note:

- If `$value` contained a `\` followed by an *actual newline* (probably not a concern with configuration-file entries), that newline would be *removed*.
- For any other `\`-prefixed character - not just `\"` - (only) the `\` is removed.
- No expansions of any kind are performed, and other string formats that the *shell* supports aren't supported (such as automatic concatenation of adjacent strings `"ab""cd"` to yield `abcd`).

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268513/45375) of mine for a safe templating solution that restricts expansions to embedded *variable* references (prevents command substitutions).

---

#### Optional background information

**`read`** - without the `-r` option - interprets `\`-based sequences only in the sense that, with the exception discussed below, it ***removes* the `\` before a `\<char>` sequence**; it **does *not* perform expansion of control-character escape sequences such as `\n`**.

The only expansion of sorts `read` *does* perform is **if a `\` is followed by an *actual* newline (LF character)**, in which **the newline is removed too**, which points to the **main purpose of `\`-escaping for `read`: line continuation**.
From the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html):

> By default, unless the `-r` option is specified, `<backslash>` shall act as an escape character. An unescaped `<backslash>` shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a `<newline>`. If a `<newline>` follows the `<backslash>`, the read utility shall interpret this as line continuation. The `<backslash>` and `<newline>` shall be removed before splitting the input into fields. All other unescaped `<backslash>` characters shall be removed after splitting the input into fields.

The **`-r` option turns interpretation of `\` sequences *off***, which is the desired behavior in the vast majority of cases.
Therefore, **it is advisable to use `-r` routinely**, unless you explicitly need processing of `\` sequences.

Comment: Thanks.  This kind of quote stripping is the one I am afraid I will have to fall back on (and am hoping to work around).  It is not perfect (e.g. if the string to be interpreted is `"first part""second part"`, the result will not be what normal shell processing would provide, but it is better than launching an external command for each assignment (in the sense that I can live with the tradeoff on expressivity given my purpose).  The `read` trick I had not thought about, I always use `-r`, I would have to play with it to see if I prefer with or without.  Thanks!

Comment: What I would really want is some kind of `safeval`, which does all safe expansions (most notably nothing with `$()`), but performs simple variable substitution and `${}` expansions (that do not recursively involve `$()` or any other construct with potential side-effects).

Comment: @Fred: Please see my update - I've added a link to answer that may provide what you're looking for. Generally, though, I wonder whether it's a good idea to store shell-specific constructs configuration files. Yes, using `-r` almost always makes sense - truthfully, this is the first real-world use case where _not_ using it is helpful.

Comment: Could you explicitly do the eval in rbash on a readonly or tmp fs?

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the reference, this may be the beginning of something nice for me.  Let me rephrase the idea to make sure I understand : first, replace any `(`, `[`, and single quote with bytes that are not usually found in text files, then perform the `eval` (which is then safe), and finally revert the replacements.  Is there any reason this would not work using shell `${...}` replacements instead of `tr`?  Could the replacement be performed only when `$` is the preceding character, so that for instance assigning an array would remain possible?

Comment: @Fred: Your paraphrasing of the approach used in the `expandVars` function in my linked answer sounds correct. In principle you should be able to use parameter expansion in lieu of `tr`, but it'll be cumbersome. I'm not sure what you mean re arrays, but the current function does expand references to arrays a whole. If you have more questions, I suggest you create a _new question_ (but feel free to ping me).

Comment: @mklement0  I will whip up something and make it work, then probably post another question to validate the solution is sound.  I will probably go with expansions despite a few more lines of code, as I expect avoiding the call an external program to be worth it to avoid a dependency an gain a bit of speed (code I will code once and reuse a lot).  Thanks!