# How to replace string with an environment variable in sed command in MacOS shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Below is a `sed` command used to replace the string `$RUNTIME_DIR` defined in `redis.conf` with an environment variable `RUNTIME_DIR`. But I always get an error

```
sed "s/\$RUNTIME_DIR/${RUNTIME_DIR}/" redis.conf
sed: 1: "s/$RUNTIME_DIR//use ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'u'
```

what is the correct way to use `sed` command with a variable as the replacement?

The content of the variable is `/users/joey/dev/bigcrunch//runtime`

Comment: Could you provide a sample line from `redis.conf` on how it is defined?

Comment: Could you also show us the content of the variable? My guess is that it contains a slash, and perhaps starts with `/usr...`.

Comment: Darn, @tripleee ... I was going to answer this as a templating question, not a sed one!  :)

Comment: If you have another duplicate you want to link, I'll be happy to add it to the duplicate box if you don't yet have that privilege. (Oh, but you do, it seems.)

Comment: @tripleee, I've added an old standby to the dupe list.. [This other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914220/1072112) is older and almost identical question to this one, but I think it contains bad answers. Generally, I point people at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles, which is about as authoritative a source as I know. I'll leave this comment for the wiki link.   :)

Comment: There's a bunch of possible canonicals and they should properly all be marked as duplicates. I simply picked my top google hit for "sed replace variable slash" so I am definitely not emotionally invested in this particular one. Maybe join the [`#!/bin/bash` chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98569/bin-bash) for brief coordination?