# Why does flutterfire configure not replace my old GoogleService-Info.plist file?

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, plist

When I first run `flutterfire configure` in my flutter app, 4 files were generated. `firebase_options.dart`, `google-services.json`, `firebase_app_id_file.json` and `GoogleServices-Info.plist`.

When I tried to use `flutterfire configure` again to link my app to a development version of my app (following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639268/switching-between-multiple-firebase-projects-environments-in-flutter)), I was only prompted to change 3 of the files like this:

> The google-services.json file already exists but for a different Firebase project (betacentre-dev). Do you want to replace it with Firebase project thinking-digit-343408? · yes

After selecting `yes` for all of them, only GoogleService-Info.plist was unchanged, yet it is clearly crucial for firebase to work (since `flutterfire configure` added it in the first place, and it is referenced in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) and also [this guide](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), and it contains identifiers for my firebase project, and my app still communicates with the original project).

Is this a bug? Why is it behaving this way?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug. I ended up creating a script to call `rm ios/{your_target_name}/GoogleService-Info.plist` before calling `flutterfire configure` with a few preset options.