# How to replace a string of different length through file handling in tcl

Tags: string, replace, tcl

Want to replace SVT-ATL in all the lines of file with SVT without disturbing other text.
Using below code:

```
set fileDest3 "$dirName/$filename"
set fpr [open $fileDest3 r+]
set line [gets $fpr]
regsub -all "SVT-ATL" $line "SVT" line
puts $fpr "$line"
```

Comment: Are you intend to read only the first line from the text file ? You are not using `gets` in a loop. If you want to replace, then better to write a file and rename it to the old file.

Comment: No, whole file needs to be changed. It is just a piece of code, and i do not want to write into another file i want to edit only those lines that contains the word in the same file

Answer (score 2):

Because you're changing the length of lines, you *must* rewrite the whole file. (Well, you could theoretically leave the lines before the first thing being changed a lot, but that's a whole bunch more work.) The simplest way is to read it all in, `string map` to perform the change (in the simplest case; `regsub` if things are trickier) and then write it all back out (`chan seek` to the beginning first, of course). As you're shortening things, you'll need to finish with a `chan truncate`.

```
set fileDest3 "$dirName/$filename"
set fpr [open $fileDest3 r+]
set newContents [string map {"SVT-ATL" "SVT"} [read $fptr]]
chan seek $fptr 0
puts -nonewline $fptr $newContents
chan truncate $fptr
close $fptr
```

The `puts` has a `-nonewline` so you don't get an extra terminating newline; the one that was there originally will still be in (as we're reading it *all* in and not just line-by-line).

Answer (score 1):

```
package require fileutil

proc cmd data {
    string map {SVT-ATL SVT} $data
}

if {[catch {fileutil::updateInPlace [file join $dir $filename] cmd}]} {
    error "failed to change file"
}
```

The Tcllib `fileutil::updateInPlace` command takes care of the low-level details of opening, reading, applying a given command to the content, truncating, writing, and closing files that you want updated. You simply provide a command like `cmd` here and enjoy the odds ever being in your favor.

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [error](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/error.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

The `fileutil` package is documented here: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
set timestamp [clock format [clock seconds] -format {%Y%m%d%H%M%S}]

set filename "yourfilenamehere.txt"
set temp     $filename.tmp.$timestamp
set backup   $filename.bak.$timestamp

set in  [open $filename r]
set out [open $temp     w]

# line-by-line, read the original file
while {[gets $in line] != -1} {

    # Modifying $line by replacing the 'SVT-AL' with 'SVT'
    regsub -all "SVT-ATL" $line "SVT" line

    # then write the modified line to 'tmp' file
    puts $out $line
}

close $in
close $out

# This is to rename the current file to backup file
file rename -force $filename $backup
# This is to rename the tmp file to the original file
file rename -force $temp $filename
```

Reference : [Glenn Jackman & Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819919/974155)

**Update :**

If you don't want to create a new file, then at least, as Jerry pointed out, we can read all the file content at once, apply our string replacement and then write back to file.

```
# Reading the file content
set fd [ open "yourfilename" r ] 
set data [ read $fd ]
close $fd

# Replacing the string now... 
regsub -all "SVT-ATL" $data "SVT" data

# Opening file with 'w' mode which will truncate the file
set fd [ open "yourfilename" w ]
puts $fd $data
close $fd
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for the solution, but the above solution is not working fine for large size files like if file has 10000 lines of code.

Comment: Is there any method of opening a file in replacing mode not in overwriting mode ???

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no replace mode for file handling in tcl.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider

```
exec sed -i {s/SVT-ATL/SVT/g} "$dirName/$filename"
```